# Can I see how many times my Google doc has been viewed?

Tags: google-docs

I've recently posted a Google Document on a forum and I'd like to know how many people saw and when. I could see how people were opening and closing the doc live, with those user icons popping up next to the `share` button. But nothing in the UI indicates where (if at all) a document stores it's viewing statistics.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using a URL shortener service which allows tracking who clicked the url. One of the more popular URL shorteners is [Bitly](https://bitly.com/) but any would work fine.

There is no native way in Google Drive to see how many people viewed a file. One potential would be a Google App Script that "triggers" when the document is opened, but that would not be counting unique views and would just count any document open. It would also require some Javascript knowledge to make a script that would count that.

Comment: Is this still the only solution in 2021?

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell Unfortunately, yes. I mean you could probably technically also use Google App Scripts and have it trigger when the document is open and then make it count that way. Problem is that I don't think there would be anyway to count unique views so it wouldn't be too useful as someone may just open it multiple times.

Answer (score -3):

Yes this option is available

Open the required sheet you want to view the revision of

Under file option click on see history reversion

When click this the column will appear in the right side of the same sheet displaying the recession history and other data